# Let p, q, r be distinct primes greater than 3, and let n = pqr.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Show that if $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ satisfies $x^{2} \equiv  9\mod{n}$

then $x \equiv  ±3 \mod{p}$, $x \equiv  ±3 \mod{q}$ and  $x \equiv  ±3 \mod {r}$.

I'm not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could use a better title.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** From the given information we get, for example, that $(x-3)(x+3)\equiv 0\pmod{p}$. So $p$ divides $(x-3)(x+3)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $n=pqr$, such that $x^{2} \equiv 9 \mod {n} $, ie,  $\exists k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that 
\begin{eqnarray}
x^{2}-9 &=& nk\\
(x-3)(x+3)&=&nk
\end{eqnarray}
Now

1. P.D. $x\equiv 3\mod{p}$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&nk\\
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&pqrk\\
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&p(qrk)\\
   x&\equiv&\pm3\mod{p}
   \end{eqnarray}
2. P.D. $x\equiv 3\mod{q}$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&nk\\
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&pqrk\\
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&q(prk)\\
   x&\equiv&\pm3\mod{q}
   \end{eqnarray}
3. P.D. $x\equiv 3\mod{r}$
   \begin{eqnarray}
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&nk\\
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&pqrk\\
   (x-3)(x+3)&=&r(pqk)\\
   x&\equiv&\pm3\mod{r}
   \end{eqnarray}